# What is the best way to upgrade a C library that comes with Fedora? Manually?

Tags: fedora, java, repository, dnf, jpeg

I am having an issue with JavaFX, which I posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360620/javafx-is-not-displaying-jpg-files). Basically, the Java library calls a native function that needs the version 90 of the JPEG library. Here's the error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 90
```

What I think that is odd, is that even an older version of the Java library I'm trying to use (JavaFX 11) requires a newer version of the JPEG library that is available on my system. I'm using Fedora 33, which is a very current operating system, and I always keep it updated.

Appearently, that library is updated on Fedora 34, but why is my JPEG so outdated in a cutting-edge system, like Fedora 33? Also, what is the canonical way to upgrade this library? Should I compile and replace it manually? I'm not sure what library I should update.

The command `ldconfig -p | grep -P jpe?g` returns:

```
    libmjpegutils-2.1.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libmjpegutils-2.1.so.0
    libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libjpeg.so.62
    libjpeg.so.62 (libc6) => /lib/libjpeg.so.62
    libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libjpeg.so
    libgdcmjpeg16.so.3.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgdcmjpeg16.so.3.0
    libgdcmjpeg12.so.3.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgdcmjpeg12.so.3.0
    libgdcmjpeg8.so.3.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgdcmjpeg8.so.3.0
```

And the command `rpm -qa | grep -P jpe?g` returns:

```
    libjpeg-turbo-2.0.5-5.fc33.i686
    libjpeg-turbo-2.0.5-5.fc33.x86_64
    libjpeg-turbo-devel-2.0.5-5.fc33.x86_64
    mjpegtools-libs-2.1.0-20.fc33.x86_64
    openjpeg2-2.3.1-10.fc33.x86_64
```

Should I update openjpeg or libjpeg-turbo?

Comment: What's the output of `rpm -qf /lib/libjpeg.so.62`?

Comment: According to https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libjpeg.so.9 , libjpeg9 isn't in Fedora 34 either.    As for "outdated", it isn't.   `libjpeg` was forked years ago into `libjpegturbo`.  Most distros have packages for libjpeg-turbo, which is API compatible with libjpeg up to around `libjpeg` 8 (even though libjpegturbo has a .so version number of .62 - different development track/version numbering).   Some distros also provide packages for the non-forked libjpeg (e.g. debian has packages for `libjpeg8` and `libjpeg9`).

Comment: BTW, libjpeg-turbo devs [announced in 2019](https://libjpeg-turbo.org/About/Jpeg-9) that they won't be implementing the libjpeg9 API.

Comment: your best bet is to search to see if anyone has packaged libjpeg9 for fedora.  If they have and you think they're a reputable, trustworthy source, install the package.  Otherwise, compile and install it yourself (use [checkinstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org) or GNU [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) so you can easily uninstall or upgrade it without it being a package)

Comment: Alternatively, maybe JavaFX has a compile-time option to use libjpeg-turbo instead of libjpeg?   Debian's `libopenjfx-jni` v 11.0.11+0-1 package depends on `libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1)` so it looks like it's possible....I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to both java and jpeg libraries, though, so don't take my word for it.  Everything I've mentioned above came from about 5 minutes with duckduckgo.

Comment: @muru libjpeg-turbo-2.0.5-5.fc33.i686. Hehe, I had forgotten about this rpm option parameter. It was dawn, I should be sleepy.

Comment: @cas Thank you, I appreciate the info. I'm curious about the approach took by the Debian developers. I've dig the the JavaFX documentation for a specific parameter, but didn't find anything related to it. Maybe the Debian version has a specific patch. I will try to find out how they did it for learning purposes, but it will take a while because I have basic C knowledge and none C++ knowledge (at the moment), so it's kinda hard.

Comment: @cas The best quick solution for me to solve the problem now would be compiling libjpeg and distribute it within my application package, I believe. I can override the library present on the OS at runtime with a JVM parameter (-Djava.library.path). But when it is compiled, it takes permanent OS path preffixes (/usr/share/lib, for instance). Do you if there is a way to configure make to compile it into an independent single folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fetch Fedora's 34 RPM ( libjpeg-turbo-2.0.90-2.fc34.x86_64.rpm or libjpeg-turbo-2.0.90-2.fc34.i686.rpm ) and unpack the JPEG library anywhere you want or compile and install the library to e.g. /usr/local
2. Run this app this way:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/libjpeg.so.62 application
```